# R dplyr rowwise mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

Good morning all, this is my first time posting on stack overflow. Thank you for any help!

I have 2 dataframes that I am using to analyze stock data. One data frame has dates among other information, we can call it df:

```
df1 <- tibble(Key = c('a','b','c'), i =11:13, date= ymd(20110101:20110103))
```

The second dataframe also has dates and other important information.

```
df2 <-tibble(Answer = c('a','d','e','b','f','c'), j =14:19, date= ymd(20150304:20150309))
```

Here is what I want to do:
For each row in df1, I need to:

-Find the date in df2 where, for when df2$answer is the same as df1$key, it is the closest to that row's date in df1.

-Then extract information for another column in that row in df2, and put it in a new row in df1.

The code i tried:

```
df1 %>%
 group_by(Key, i) %>%
 mutate(
`New Column` =  df2$j[
  which.min(subset(df2$date, df2$Answer== Key) - date)])
```

This has the result:

```
Key       i date       `New Column`
1 a        11 2011-01-01           14
2 b        12 2011-01-02           14
3 c        13 2011-01-03           14
```

This is correct for the first row, `a`. In `df2`, the closest date is `2015-03-04`, for which the value of `j` is in fact `14`.

However, for the second row, `Key=b`, I want `df2` to subset to only look at dates for rows where `df2$Answer = b`. Therefore, the date should be `2015-03-07`, for which `j =17`.

Thank you for your help!

Jesse

Comment: Rename the date columns so they don't share a name, `left_join` the data on `"Answer" = "Key"`, `arrange` by the difference in the date columns, `group_by` Answer and `slice` the top row from each group (smallest date difference, because of the sorting).

Comment: Thanks for your help Gregor! Are you saying to `left-join` with df2 on left, df1 on right, like `left_join(df2, df1, by = c("Answer" = "Key"))` ? If I do it the other way it is not accepted since `Key` only has 3 values and `Answer` has 6

Comment: `df1 %>% 
  right_join(df2, by = c('Key' = 'Answer')) %>% 
  group_by(Key) %>% 
  arrange(abs(date.x - date.y)) %>% 
  slice(1)` Is Gregor's suggestion I believe (Or switch `df2` and `df1` and change `right_join` to `left_join`)

Comment: Hi Ryan and Gregor. The problem with this suggestion, while helpful, is that in the actual data, the dates are not exactly matching. If I try to join by `Key= Answer`, for each key there are many matching answers, and if do it by c("Key" = "Answer", "date = "date), the dates are not exactly matching, that is why I need to do which.min, to find the closest date to link them up, not the same date.

Comment: You're ignoring everything in my comment after the join. You join by Key = Answer, which does result in many matches. The rest of my comment tells you how to find the closest date and get rid of all the other rows: arrange, group_by, slice. This does the same thing as your `which.min`, but in an easier workflow.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand it better now, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("Key" = "Answer")) %>% 
  mutate(date_diff = abs(difftime(date.x, date.y, units = "secs"))) %>% 
  group_by(Key) %>% 
  arrange(date_diff) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

We are first joining the two data frames with `left_join`.  Yes, I'm aware there are possibly multiple dates for each `Key`, bear with me.

Next, we calculate (with `mutate`) the absolute value (`abs`) of the difference between the two dates `date.x` and `date.y`.

Now that we have this, we will group the data by `Key` using `group_by`.  This will make sure that each distinct `Key` will be treated separately in subsequent calculations.

Since we've calculated the `date_diff`, we can now re-order (`arrange`) the data for each `Key`, with the smallest `date_diff` as first for each `Key`.

Finally, we are only interested in that first, smallest `date_diff` for each `Key`, so we can discard the rest using `slice(1)`.

This pipeline gives us the following:

```
  Key       i date.x         j date.y     date_diff
  <chr> <int> <date>     <int> <date>     <time>   
1 a        11 2011-01-01    14 2015-03-04 131587200
2 b        12 2011-01-02    17 2015-03-07 131760000
3 c        13 2011-01-03    19 2015-03-09 131846400
```

Comment: Since these are dates, not datetimes, you could simplify to `date_diff = abs(date.x - date.y)` to get the difference in days.

Comment: Definitely agree with you in OP's instance.  However, I was trying to keep my answer flexible for others that stumble onto this thread with a similar question.

Comment: Hi, thank you as well for your helpful comment. My problem is that in the actual dataset, for each key there are multiple rows, so when I try to do the left_join, I get the error `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 23.1 Mb`.

Comment: I just had to add more memory to R using `memory.limit`